# Regular expression to split on letters

Tags: c#, regex

Using .net, what is a regular expression to split on, pulling out groups of letters?

I tried @"[a-zA-Z]*", then regex.Split... as an example, but I'm totally lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The * doesn't require at least one character to match. Try

```
@"[a-zA-Z]+"
```

instead.

Actually, if you want the letters themselves, don't use `Regex.Split`, use `Regex.Match` or `Regex.Matches`. The `Split` version will capture what's **between** the strings of letters.

Comment: Will it work with different alphabet specific letters? In other words is it code-page independent?

Comment: Brilliant, I've never come to grips with regex, they don't seem to fit in my brain for some reason :)

Comment: @MPękalski, this will only work for the 26 ASCII English letters, if you want full unicode you can use `\p{L}`

Comment: @MPękalski - If you mean characters like the **ę** in your name, what you want is probably `\p{L}`. Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: @Ian - Don't worry, we were all like that not too long ago. The best regex reference I know of is http://www.regular-expressions.info/ , so if you want to try and fit them into your brain that's a good place to start. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but, just in case you already know the kind of caracters that might separate the words you could simply use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).

Of course this is only if you there are a few specific characters separating the words, such as spaces or commas, like `"word,word.word word"` but **not** if you want to pick up groups of letters in the middle of a bunch of other stuff like in `"lk234lkv234.2@#$dfff(*"`

I know I'm going a bit away from the original question, but still you might find this useful

Comment: Absolutely. I had considered string.split, but I only know the valid bits critera rather than the invalid bits if that makes sense. Good advice though.